# Automatically add quotes

Tags: punctuation, environments, quoting

I would like to create a new environment which will behave similar to `quote`, but with quotes added. I tried something like this:

```
\newenvironment{newquote}{\itshape\color{blue!20!black!30!green}\begin{quote}“}{”\end{quote}}
```

But that produces space beetween quotes and text which I don't want.

[image: Unwanted space beetween quotes and text]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd be tempted to look at the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package to do what you want. However, for the matter in hand I suspect you are using input such as

```
\begin{newquote}
  He who plants a garden plants happiness.
\end{newquote}
```

which means there is a space added at the end of the line. Try

```
\newenvironment{newquote}
 {\itshape\color{blue!20!black!30!green}\begin{quote}“\ignorespaces}
 {\unskip”\end{quote}}
```

or add a `%` to kill the end of the line in your source:

```
\begin{newquote}%
  He who plants a garden plants happiness.%
\end{newquote}
```

Comment: There's also a space at the beginning.  I tried `\xspace` but that didn't work, `\ignorespaces` did, though.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I was about to write about the space at the beginning as well.
@Joseph Wright: Could you add the `\ignorespaces` to your answer. That makes it possible to use the desired input
    
    \begin{newquote}
    He who plants a garden plants happiness
    \end{newquote}

Comment: @Andrew: Oh yes, so there is. @ipavlic: done

Comment: @Joseph: For your last piece of code you'd also need a `%` after `\begin{newquote}`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Hendrik:  Hmm, yes. I'll sort that.

Comment: @Joseph: Your answer now subsumes mine so I'll delete it.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry about that :-)

Comment: I'd been wondering how to eat space with a macro. Now I know!

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps this is overkill. Some time ago I was looking for something simular. I wrote a small script that was able to show small quotes to introduce a chapter in a book I am writing. The code:

```
\newcommand{\chapterquote}[2]{
  \begin{figure*}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[text width=12cm,anchor=center] (Q) at (0,0) {\Large\textit{#1}};
      \node[gray,anchor=north east] (Ql) at (Q.north west) {\Huge\textbf{``}};
      \node[gray,anchor=north west] (Qr) at (Q.south east) {\Huge\textbf{''}};
      \node[black!80,anchor=north east] (Qa) at (Qr.north west) {\small - #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure*}
}
```

You will need the to use `tikz package`. As an example:

```
\chapterquote{To be, or not to be}{William Shakespeare}
```

This produces something like:

[image]

Feel free to experiment with this custom command. You can for instance modify the color and size.

Comment: Thanks, that seems very nice. I am very happy with TikZ in general.